# Incrementing Values with If Statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

**Here is what I am trying to do:**

I have data. This data is unstructured and I am trying to make it look neat so that I can do something with it.

There is a column called "Address". If the address column takes the value "ADDRESS" then I want to do a count where the value takes 1. If it is anything other than "ADDRESS" I want the count to increment.

**What it currently does:**
My counter takes the value of 1 if the value "ADDRESS" appears, and it increments if the value is not "ADDRESS" but the value does not reset itself. It keeps going as if nothing ever happened.

**My code:**

```
var count_y = -1;

for(a = 0; a<= New_Row_Num; a++){
    if(Address == 'ADDRESS'){
        count_y = 1;
        //count_y == 0;
    }else{
        count_y += 1;
    }
}
```

**What I have tried that did not work other than the code posted above:**
I tried creating an array and assigning it a value of 1. If the "address" column has the value 'ADDRESS' the array goes back to being a value of 1, otherwise the array would increment in value. This had the same effect as above, just with different numbers.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong, thank you.

Comment: You're not accessing an array element, you're just accessing the global variable `Address`.

Comment: Your loop iterates over the variable `a`, but never uses those values.  So in each iteration of the loop, the value of `Address` does not change, so the condition in the loop will never change ... always executing the `count_y += 1` line.

Comment: Why doesn't it use those values? I have the "a++" at the end? I don't understand where I messed up.

Comment: You aren't doing something like `Address = addr_array[a];`.

Comment: please add the data array as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I needed to do. Thanks anyway for the help guys.

My Solution:

```
var x = getProcessCount('r');
var y; //I am not initializing the variable here.
var z; //I am not initializing the variable here.
trans_Status=CONTINUE_TRANSFORMATION;


if(x==1) y=1; //This is where it is initialized.
if(address=='ADDRESS'){

    y = 1;
    trans_Status=CONTINUE_TRANSFORMATION;

}else{

    y+=1;
    trans_Status=CONTINUE_TRANSFORMATION;
}

if(x==1) z=0; //This is where it is initialized.
if(address=='ADDRESS'){

    z+=1
    trans_Status=CONTINUE_TRANSFORMATION;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have an Address array which contains the address then the below code should work,

```
var count_y = -1;

for(a = 0; a<= New_Row_Num; a++){
 if(Address[a] == 'ADDRESS'){
    count_y = 1;
    //count_y == 0;
 }else{
    count_y += 1;
 }
}
```